# AWS instance not working in US Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, websocket

I have configured AWS free tier EC2 instance for my ipad app. It's working perfect for Indian region but its not working for US region. I am using this sever for socket api. All socket api is working in India but not working in united states.

To listen the socket server i have created a custom port and also added in AWS custom port. Everything is working correctly at india but not in US.I could not replicate the issue also could not found any solution after research.

Could you please check inbound and outbound security.
[image]
[image]
What could be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add more diagnostic information to prove US instance is not good. Includes, netstat on ec2 instance, configured security groups associated to each instance. Without those information it will be hard to predict what is going wrong.

Comment: could you please check i have added inbound and outbound configuration pic.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is "not working for US region?"  Where is the server located, and how is it being accessed (by hostname or IP), and what error is being observed?